# In computer terminology, what is a "non-directory" called?

Tags: scala, file, filesystems, terminology, algebraic-data-types

This question might sound really naive but I understand that in a hierarchical filesystem, directories can contain other files. But, I am having trouble coming up with a good name for things that are not directories (i.e. vanilla "files") - I can't just call them files since `class Directory extends Files`.
I want to do type-safe operations (e.g. the compile will fail if I try to list a file or read a directory):

```
sealed trait File {
  def path: Path
}
case class Directory(path: Path, children: Iterable[File]) extends File
case class VanillaFile?(path: Path, contents: Iterable[Byte]) extends File
```

What should be a better name for `VanillaFile`?

EDIT:
As pointed out, there is one more thing in certain file systems:

```
case class SymbolicLink(target: File) extends File
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily a good idea to classify files as "directory" or "not directory". e.g. look at the "is*" methods in `java.nio.Files` - you can also have symbolic links.

Comment: >> What should be a better name for VanillaFile - StrawberryFile

Comment: @AndyTurner: Good point. But, the question still stands. What do I call a vanilla file (i.e. something that is not a directory nor a link)?

Comment: How about `DataFile`?

Comment: @wrick If you are insistent that your application needs a type which is not a directory (and so is a regular file or symlink), I would call it `NotADirectoryFile` or `RegularFileOrSymlink`. "vanilla" would not be a widely-understood name; ScaryWombat's alternative is facetious, but it's equally valid in my mind.

Comment: @ThomasStets: Is that a standard terminology? I don't want to invent something on my own since this is part of a library that would be used by a lot of other people too.

Comment: @ThomasStets what if it's not data?

Comment: @ThomasStets hmm, what if the file is empty and just exists as a marker? It wouldn't be a _data_ file then :)

Comment: @AndyTurner: See my edit regarding symbolic links. `RegularFile` sounds better than `VanillaFile` I guess ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner), "regular file" is a standard term:

- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types
- Bash: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html
- Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isRegularFile%28%29

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to name the `Trait` something else, such as `FileSystemNode` or `FileSystemEntry` and then just use `File`, `Directory`, `SymLink` etc. Of course, maybe better to ask linguists than engineers on this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150806/what-is-the-noun-for-either-a-file-or-folder